# IHttpContextAccessor is null in class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, httpcontext

I have problem when I'm trying to get httpcontext from IHttpContextAccessor field is always null in class.

There is my startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserContextServices, UserContextService>();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = ".AdventureWorks.Session";
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    });
}
```

This is My UserContext Class which implements IUserContext interface

```
public class UserContextService : IUserContextServices
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
    PQADBContext _context = new PQADBContext();

    public UserContextService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        contextAccessor = accessor;
    }

   public UserContextService()
    {

    }

    public HttpContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            return contextAccessor.HttpContext;
        }
    }
   public int UserID()
    {
       return Context.Session.GetID("UserID").ConvertToInt();
    }
    public bool isLogin()
    {
        return Context.Session.GetBoolean("isLogin").ConvertToBool();
    }
      public UserAccount CreateSession(LoginViewModel logindata, bool EncryptPwd = true)
    {
        string error;
        error = "";
        try
        {
            string EncPwd = EncryptPwd ? EncryptDecryptHelper.Encrypt(logindata.Password) : logindata.Password;
            var UserDetail =_context.UserAccount.Where(e => e.P_No == logindata.PNo && e.Password == EncPwd).SingleOrDefault();


            if (UserDetail != null)
            {

                //HttpContext.Session.SetInt32()

                // ///put all the properties in session variables
                 Context.Session.SetBoolean("isLogin", true);
                Context.Session.SetID("UserID",UserDetail.AccountId);
                Context.Session.SetID("P_No",Convert.ToInt32(UserDetail.P_No));
                Context.Session.SetBoolean("isActive", true);
                Context.Session.SetBoolean("Email", true);
                Context.Session.SetID("RoleId", 1);
                Context.Session.SetString("userName", "admin"); 
   }
```

httpContext available in above class and also set the Session values but when i try to access httpcontext in this class it gives me null object reference

```
public class UserService
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
    public IUserContextServices _userContext = new UserContextService();
   public UserService()
    {  
    }
 public bool CreateEmployee(AppEmployees appemployee, int RoleId, bool isEmailSend, out string error)
    {
appemployee.CreatedBy = _userContext.UserID(); //this line shows null reference exception
        appemployee.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use default constructor in your UserService?

You use next code:

```
public IUserContextServices _userContext = new UserContextService();
```

Of course here you have null for `IHttpContextAccessor`.

You need to use DI in your UserService.

Example:

```
private readonly IUserContextService _userContextService;
public UserService(IUserContextService userContextService)
{  
    _userContextService = userContextService;
}
```

There is good [post](https://stackify.com/net-core-dependency-injection/) about DI in .NET Core.

Comment: I need to access current session in any class how would i do that? i mean how to call IhttpContextAccessor in any class?

Comment: @AfaqRajput you need to use Injection via constructor. It is the simplest way to retrieve IHttpContextAccessor in necessary class (as described in the answer). Also you can use Property Injection using [Autofac](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection). In this case you can use IHttpContextAccessor as public property.

Answer (score 3):

You are newing up the `UserContextService` using the parameterless constructor

```
public IUserContextServices _userContext = new UserContextService();
```

instead of relying on Dependency Injection.

You need to configure your `UserService` to be used with your DI container - via constructor injection that would be

```
public class UserService
{
    private readonly IUserServiceContext _userServiceContext;

    public UserService(IUserServiceContext userServiceContext)
    {
        _userServiceContext = userServiceContext;
    }
}
```

You will also need to amend your Startup.cs to register the `UserService` and you may want it to implement an interface too

Answer (score 0):

If you have set UserId directly as

```
public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
}
```

This way you might get null UserId most of the time instead create httpContextAccessor field first like

```
public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
     this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
public string UserId { get { return httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); } }
```

Then get UserId, this way the problem of getting null UserId will be resolved.